# Why are the colors wrong?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a graph made with `ggplot2`, I chose a color for the fill and another for the border, but the border color is overlapping the fill color, even if I decrease its size. Generating the graph on macOS doesn't return any errors, only on Windows.

I'm using the same version of `R` and `ggplot2` in the two systems.

Graph on Windows 10:

[image]

Graph on macOS Catalina:

[image]

Code used in both systems:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
library(httr)
library(openxlsx)

url <- httr::GET("https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalGeral",
                 httr::add_headers("X-Parse-Application-Id" =
                                     "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")) %>%
  httr::content() %>%
  '[['("results") %>%
  '[['(1) %>%
  '[['("arquivo") %>%
  '[['("url")

dados <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(url) %>%
  filter(is.na(municipio), is.na(codmun))

for(i in 9:16) {
  dados[,i] <- as.numeric(dados[,i]) 
}

dados[,8] <- convertToDate(dados[,8])

dados_mm7d <- dados %>%
  mutate(mm7dCasos = rollmean(casosNovos, 7, fill = list(NA, NULL, NA), align = "right"),
         mm7dCasos = ifelse(is.na(mm7dCasos), 0, mm7dCasos),
         mm7dCasos = ifelse(is.infinite(mm7dCasos), 0, mm7dCasos)) %>%
  filter(data > "2020-03-30", !is.na(estado))

dados %>%
  filter(data > "2020-03-23", !is.na(estado)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = casosNovos), na.rm = TRUE, color = "black", fill = "#0181ae", size = 0.1, width = 0.6) +
  geom_line(data = dados_mm7d, aes(x = data, y = mm7dCasos), color = "#dd0533", size = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2', labels = scales::comma) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2, 8192)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "2 week") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey10", linetype = "solid")) +
  facet_wrap(~estado, nrow = 3)
```

Comment: Aren't they both imperfect? Windows doesn't show the fill color of the columns, but the Mac doesn't show the black outlines of the columns. Neither device has enough pixels to show the bars _and_ a black outline - they are far too small. If you prefer the look of the Mac plot, just remove the `color = "black"` call from `geom_col`. If you want fill and outline on this plot, you could try printing it onto a football field...

Comment: Because of the size of the image, I think it is not possible to see, but on the mac it has the black border, but very small. And I can't remove the ```color = "black"``` because I need the border to be black.

Comment: But your plots each have about 80 columns, and there are 9 of them across the page. Even if you have 1 pixel for outline and 2 for fill, you have four pixels per column. That's 80 * 4 * 9 = 2880 pixels. Then you need at least another 10% for the axes and margins. So unless you have a monitor that can display over 3000 pixels across, the Mac must be doing some sub-pixel approximations. That's great, but it hardly counts as an "error" in Windows that it can't render more pixels than your monitor has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot your graph using Cairo to get anti-aliased graphs on Windows:

```
install.packages("Cairo")
library(Cairo)

Cairo("graph.png", units="in", width=8, height=7, dpi=200)
here goes your plot code
dev.off()
```